# Close android camera intent after take a picture

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have this simple code to take a single picture and return to caller activity:

```
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + directory_path
    + "/"
    + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)
    + ".jpg"));
camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(camera_intent, 1);

MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(camera_intent, 0);
```

But the camera intent closes itself only after two pictures. So, after I take one picture, the camera intent is still active. After I take another picture, only now, camera intent get closed and `onActivityResult` gets called.

What's wrong?

EDIT:
I've try to print a Log message into onActivityResult, and i've noticed that onActivityResult is call twice, but only after the second picture (and after camera intent close itself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are calling twice startActivityForResult

```
startActivityForResult(camera_intent, 1);

//MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(camera_intent, 0);
```

remove one of them.

Comment: **Woooooooooooow... so stupid! I did the exact same mistake!** I called startActivityForResult once inside `if` and once outside... The most time-consuming mistakes are the silliest ones...  xD